# Is there a more efficient way to handle this array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am a beginner in java, and I wanted to make an array with objects, in my case elements, but I can't seem to think of a more efficient way of doing it. Can somebody please help!

```
elements[0] = hydrogen;
elements[1] = lithium;
elements[2] = beryllium;
elements[3] = sodium;
elements[4] = magnesium;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"?

Comment: Define: "more efficient". Did you perhaps mean "shorter code"?

Comment: Also are these all elements in array?

Comment: did you mean easier to use with "more efficient"?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `elements` is an `Element[]`:

```
Element[] elements = {
    hydrogen, lithium, beryllium, sodium, magnesium
};
```

I'm not sure that it is more efficient, but it is perhaps more concise. This syntax is described in section [10.6 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6), and in Oracle's [Java Tutorial on arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) under *Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array*.

Comment: Not the downvoter but it could be nice adding info about that construct (or at least some links to tutorial/documentation/specification) so OP and others could learn more about it, like fact that we may not really need `new Element[]` in this example.

Comment: @Pshemo I learn something new everyday. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object[] elements = {hydrogen, lithium, beryllium, sodium, magnesium};
```

Where `Object` should be preferably the specific type you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use this:

```
String [] elements = {"hydrogen", "lithium", "beryllium", "sodium", "magnesium"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming hydrogen, lithium, etc., are already defined this will work. You can change the type from Object to something else if the instances share a base class.

```
Object[] elements = { hydrogen, lithium, beryllium, sodium, magnesium }
```